# I have hand-drawn some work on grid paper and scanned it, how can I use Photoshop to remove the gridlines

Tags: image-processing, python-imaging-library, photoshop

The grid is a blue/green.  The work is in a black ink, and has a fair bit of variety of pressures, which I want to retain.

[Here's a link to a small selection.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1KPUsvGZZhsZS0wWVFqSGR2ZDA/view?usp=sharing)

I have Photoshop v3
My attempts have involved using Select, Color Range, and sampling some grid, then inverting.

Is there a better way?

I also have some experience with Python and PIL, if that's a useful alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a Photoshop answer, rather than a programming answer, but that seems to match your question's needs.

I applied a Black and White filter, and enabled a Blue filter, then set the Blue channel sensitivity to 300%, like this in Photoshop CC.

[image]

and got pretty good results like this:

[image]

In an older vsersion of Photoshop, you may need to go to `Image->Mode->Lab Color` and then go into the `Channels` palette and deselect `Lab` leaving just `a` and `b` channels selected, then use `Select->Color Range` to get the blues (or maybe the blacks!!!!) before going back to `RGB` mode.

Comment: Thanks Marks, i think your approach, combined with then selecting dark will be effective, will try tonight.    Can you explain what channel sensitivity means, what is actually happening when you select 300%?   Is it taking blues and making them white?

Comment: Yes, that is the net effect. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Mark, that worked quite well.  The menu option was somewhere different, and the values needed tweaking, but the essence of your answer was spot on.

Comment: Sorry Mark, that was my intention.  Done.  If you think my question could help someone else, then an upvote will also help me.